# How to sort a text by the second occurence of a letter/symbol in vim?

Tags: sorting, vim

How to sort a text by the third occurrence of a symbol, in vim? 
I'd like to sort a text like the following, by the third left bracket '['

```
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text2]description
[url=URL]url A[/url] [text1]description
                     ^
```

i.e the above text sorted will be:

```
[url=URL]url A[/url] [text1]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text2]description
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `:help :sort`:

> ```
> :[range]sor[t][!] [i][u][r][n][x][o] [/{pattern}/]
> [...]
> When /{pattern}/ is specified and there is no [r] flag
> the text matched with {pattern} is skipped, so that
> you sort on what comes after the match.
> ```

So, you need to define a `{pattern}` that skips over the first two `[` and the text up to the third `[`. There are many ways to define such a regular expression, one is:

```
:%sort /\[.\{-}\[.\{-}\ze\[/
```

This matches the first `[` (escaped, because `[...]` is a character collection), then as few characters as possible (`.\{-}`), the same again, and then stop the match before (`\ze`) the third `[` (actually, that `\ze` is not needed as all identical `[` will sort the same; the differences will only start afterwards).

#### Tip

You can develop / check your regular expression with the `/...` command (and `:set hlsearch`); it'll highlight all that is matched by it.

Comment: the `\ze` isn't necessary. because no matter the thing before the `\ze` is or is not in match result, the result will be anyway ignored by sort. aha.... you mentioned that in explanation... my bad, didn't read the explanation carefully.

Comment: @Kent: Yeah, I mention this in the answer. But I think the right reason is that the third `[` is a static character, so it doesn't influence the sorting, regardless of whether it's excluded or not. It does matter in the general case, though, so I left it in.

Comment: in "general" case, if `[` here was a dynamic char, `\ze` makes sense only if with `r` option, am I right?

Comment: @Kent Also without, to avoid that what comes after is skipped, or to put it the other way around, to have the part after `\ze` be sorted.

Comment: Thank you both for your help and the detailed posts.

Comment: Think this is easier and probably good enough for general case `%sort /.*url\]/
`

Comment: Yes, it's  quite easier. Thank you too.

Answer (score 2):

you sort on the `[` doesn't make sense, I guess you want to sort from the 3rd `[` till the end. then:

```
% sort /\v^(\[[^[]*){2}/
```

this will sort

```
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text2]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text3]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text4]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text7]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text5]description
[url=URL]url A[/url] [text1]description
```

into

```
[url=URL]url A[/url] [text1]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text2]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text3]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text4]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text5]description
[url=URL]url B[/url] [text7]description
```